# TSQL dynamic filters on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic, parameters

The table to query has the following columns :

```
(name varchar(50),values varchar(50),description varchar(50)).
```

The users want to select multiple names and a range of values for each of these name eg:

```
select * 
from table 
where (name = X and value >=1 and value <= 5 ) 
    AND (name = Y and value >=10 and value <= 25 )
    AND etc for up to 20 factors.
```

I can't use sp_execute sql to write Dynamic sql as the number of name parameters will vary . I want to aviod using exec to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: I don't know if there is a really good way to do this without a super long sp or multiple calls to the database.  Have you thought about just doing it in code?  If you are binding it to an asp object then you could just create a List<Object> and query each line and add an object to the list then use DataSource = list and then DataBind.

Comment: yes I do store the parameter selections in a dataset and pass it as a table variable to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making 4 assumptions here:

1. You have SQL-Server 2008 or later (tag is only sql-server)
2. Your criteria will always be in the format `name = Y and value >=10 and value <= 25`
3. Your values column is actually an int column (based on your where
   clause)
4. Your separate criteria should be separated by OR not and (since in
   your example you have `WHERE (Name = 'x' ..) AND (Name = 'y'...)`
   which will never evaluate to true)

Assuming the above is true then you can use table valued parameters. The first step would be to create your parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TableFilter AS TABLE 
(   Name        VARCHAR(50), 
    LowerValue  INT, 
    UpperValue  INT
);
```

Then you can create a procedure to get your filtered results

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CustomTableFilter @Filter dbo.TableFilter READONLY
AS
    SELECT  T.*
    FROM    T
    WHERE   EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    @Filter f
                WHERE   T.Name = f.Name
                AND     T.Value >= f.LowerValue 
                AND     T.Value <= f.UpperValue
            )
```

Then you can call your procedure using something like:

```
DECLARE @Filter dbo.TableFilter;
INSERT @Filter VALUES ('X', 1, 5), ('Y', 10, 25);

EXECUTE dbo.CustomTableFilter @Filter;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a4d0/3)**

Comment: 1,2,4 -correct 3.column is varchar storing int and char based on the type of 'name' column. is there a better way to filter such a column?I was planning to fiter the numeric values with range filters and union it the query filtering the string values(only a single value needs to be selected not a range) You solution was so much more simpler than the complicated way i was trying to solve it . Thanks !!

Comment: I can't really think of a better approach, other maybe multiple columns for different data types (e.g. varcharvalue, intvalue), comparing integer values stored as varchar does not work, it the same way `ABC` would be sorted before `B`, `123` would be sorted before `2`, even though 2 is clearly before 123. [Example of how it goes wrong](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85657/1)